# ruby array of arrays saving data across all insances of array, euler 18

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

for the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

nums = File::read("euler18nums.txt");   #opens file with number array inside.
parts = nums.split(' ');                #save it into instance of an array.
t = []                                  #dimension one of the array of arrays.
s = []                                  #dimension two.
j=0                                     #iteration variable.
k=0                                     #iteration variable.
n=1                                     #iteration variable.
parts.collect do |i|                    #itterates through the array that i have my data in.
    s[k] = i.to_i                       #converts strings to int and save into 2nd dimension.
    k+=1
    if k == n                           #number of itterations increase by one every time function is called.
        t[j] = s                        
        n+=1                            #saves second dimension of array into the first,-
        k=0                             #-and this is  where my problem is because it saves into and overwrites-
        test=0                          #-of the array that i have saved.
        while test != n                 #this is a test statement to print out the array so far-
            print t[test], "\n"         #-every time a new array is saved into it
            test+=1
        end
        j+=1
    end
end
print t                                 #prints out at the end, this is always just the last-
                                        #-array printed out fifteen times
```

whenever i save s into t[j] it saves into and overwrites all instances of t that have been created so far, am i misunderstanding ruby arrays, i assume that `t[5] = s` and wouldn't affect `t[4]` or `t[3]` ect. is there a way to do this in which ruby will only save the array for a specific instance or do i need to go back to `C++` for this?
the txt file for this is

```
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
```

also found at http://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not "over-writing", it is that you only ever create one second-dimension array (which you point `s` to). So you are writing pointers to the same object into each `t[j]`

Move `s = []` to the point in the code that you wish to start a new second-dimension array.

If you want to keep existing numbers in the array so far, do something like

```
s = s.clone
```

. . . which will (shallow) copy existing contents of array to a new one, and point `s` at it.

Comment: okay got it, so it doesn't set it equal to the value, it just points, that is what i was missing, thank you

Comment: yes, that's true of all Ruby objects except a very few "immediate" objects. Most notably Ruby's numbers (integers, floats etc) don't work  like pointers. The one that catches me out the most is that variables containing `String` values *are* pointers

Answer (score 1):

Looks like every element of `t` will be exactly the same `s` array, the final `t` will look something like this:

```
t[0] ---\
t[1] ----+--> s
t[2] ---/
```

When you do this:

```
t[j] = s
```

all you're doing is assigning a reference to an array to `t[j]`, you're not making a copy of the `s` array, you're just making another reference to it. The behavior is exactly the same as in C or C++ if `s` was an array or pointer.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `t[j] = s` but you probably want to assign a copy of `s` to `t[j]`:

```
t[j] = s.dup
```